# I am using a viewpager and in the one fragment of the viewpager i was attaching the recylerview and getting this nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

```
[Image of my code that is showing null pointer exception][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9C6o.png

the fragment code->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

->the activity code
package com.example.mymu

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

import com.example.my.MusicInfo
import com.example.my.PageAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main2.*

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {


    companion object {
        lateinit var mylist: MutableList<MusicInfo>
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        val song1= MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song2=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada", R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song3=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song4=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song5=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song6=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song7=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song8=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song9=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song10=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song11=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song12=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song13=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song14=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song15=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song16=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song17=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song18=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        val song19=MusicInfo("Darshan Raval","Asal Main",R.drawable.asalmain,"3:10")
        val song20=MusicInfo("Jass Manak","Prada",R.drawable.manak,"2:50")
        mylist= mutableListOf()
        mylist.add(song1)
        mylist.add(song2)
        mylist.add(song3)
        mylist.add(song4)
        mylist.add(song5)
        mylist.add(song6)
        mylist.add(song7)
        mylist.add(song8)
        mylist.add(song9)
        mylist.add(song10)
        mylist.add(song11)
        mylist.add(song12)
        mylist.add(song13)
        mylist.add(song14)
        mylist.add(song15)
        mylist.add(song16)
        mylist.add(song17)
        mylist.add(song18)
        mylist.add(song19)
        mylist.add(song20)
    
//this is the part where it is showing error//
```

val recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rv)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(mylist)
view_pager.adapter=PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
tab_layout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#7DC1C6"),resources.getColor(R.color.teal_700))
tab_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawable4)

```
    }
}``
```

Comment: It means that your recyclerview is null and isn't defined. Maybe you are accessing some other view. I would need more code from the activity and XML to point out the exact problem. Just know that the error is that your recyclerview is null so you need to fix that.

Comment: Thanku very much sir for your reply i will be sharing my code

Comment: Please format your code better

Comment: You said the code that you provided above is your fragment code. You are clearly accessing your MainActivity2 here so the reyclerview should be present in your mainactivity2 xml file and not your fragment.

Comment: If you think you are satisfied by my answer please accept it so that in future others can take help from it too

Comment: Sir but I want to use recycler view in fragment

Answer (score 0):

You said the code that you provided above is your fragment code. You are clearly accessing your MainActivity2 here so the reyclerview should be present in your mainactivity2 xml file and not your fragment. If you need recyclerview inside your fragment you need to move your recyclerview code to your fragment class and your mainactivity2 should be consisting of only the view pager